# How can I identify this SMD part with F200 marking?

Tags: identification, fuses

Can anyone help me to identify this SMD part?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

If I measured the size correctly as 1812, then it's a [Littelfuse 1812L200TH](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/2304140030_Littelfuse-1812L200THPR_C207074.pdf) PTC resettable fuse.

[image]

(Source: [lcsc.com](https://www.lcsc.com/product-detail/Resettable-Fuses_span-style-background-color-ff0-Littelfuse-span-1812L200THPR_C207074.html))

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: is this the same part? https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/394802612905

Comment: @JohnnySmartCar No, that's a different size. If you measure the part you will find the exact size. I tried to measure it from known sizes in the picture, but that's not always exact.

Comment: measures approx 4-5mm does that sound right to you?

Comment: https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/181883216045?hash=item2a5915a0ad:g:OjgAAOxyoVZTIipM&amdata=enc%3AAQAIAAABAHBWqDm4zlvtLgSPjMqy2TVM3zK9%2FVJ%2BwkBfWvRkXZIuDevmsPZqR4a3bp3IqDPA6dO%2BWpeI4Rl6suM4hjmBuWEEMbvwSufomRalnhsee27PTKBu43acsNSYgn%2Fkc%2BV84rjl51iod0nzt27VKp4m9D%2BgOYqxjf6TFEKe8mgGUYHpQastDCOvEO6ACtw1jyhgyWQyZHuOExi0G2acwIAt6fYqKPgfJanUA1YqV2ENaxYO9UuIq0AakjLfpkmB6TTWeR0CDRliIEJO8gSxJLoQ38kE%2B7VOjjwhEt%2Fmg9fHfszD7GSWkj30ptjS13IeB4GJHFwbaYChhpe%2FIlfVB4%2FGMNE%3D%7Ctkp%3ABk9SR8qm7LzNYg

Comment: @JohnnySmartCar 4-5 mm isn't good enough. 1812 is about 4.6 x 3 mm and 2016 is about 5.1 x 4.1 mm.

Comment: 4.6mm x 3mm is the correct one after a remeasure, dis this the correct one https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/181883216045 thanks for your help

Comment: @JohnnySmartCar The ebay listing is the correct part, but it's fairly expensive. You can get them a lot cheaper. See [here](https://octopart.com/search?q=1812L200THPR&currency=USD&specs=0). Also, if your question is answered, please use the [checkmark](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) to mark the question as answered.

Comment: Than you for all your help